# EC2 react with local express server

Tags: reactjs, express, amazon-ec2, server, localhost

I need some help,
I want to load my data by localhost server, and port is 3000
but at mt frontend, I will receive

the error is below
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:3000/**** (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vEDb.png)

but it's work fine on my local virtual machine, Can anyone knows what's wrong

Also, I have use cors in my backend, I have try to open the security group for my ip, all ip for port 3000

Please help me, Thanks~~

Comment: please add `cors` plugin in your backend and whitelist `localhost:3000`

Comment: Hi @NishargShah , Thank's for your reply, I already add cors plugin in my backend, and cors didn't set any whitelist, isn't cors default is accept any connect?